# Is it OK to fsfreeze --unfreeze directly after create-snapshot returns?

Tags: amazon-ec2, filesystems, snapshot, amazon-ebs, aws-cli

Assume */data* is the mount point for an EXT4 file system that occupies a whole EBS volume.
To create a backup, the file system is freezed and a snapshot is created.

```
root@ubuntu:~# fsfreeze --freeze /data
root@ubuntu:~# aws ec2 create-snapshot --volume-id vol-1234567 --description "/data snapshot"
{
    "SnapshotId": "snap-27c5ebdf",
    "Description": "/data snapshot",
    "VolumeId": "vol-1234567",
    "State": "pending",
    "VolumeSize": 250,
    "OwnerId": "744275636941",
    "StartTime": "2014-11-04T15:17:19.000Z",
    "Tags": []
}
root@ubuntu:~#
```

Is it at this point OK to run

```
root@ubuntu:~# fsfreeze --unfreeze /data
```

and start writing files under */data*?

In other words, is it OK to start using an EBS volume directly after `aws ec2 create-snapshot` returns, although the state of the snapshot might be **pending**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is OK.

Here is a quote from

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html

*You can remount and use your volume while the snapshot status is pending.*